# The module has not been deployed. NetBeans IDE 8.2

Tags: deployment, server

Initial deploying EnterpriseApplication3 to

`C:\Users\INTEL\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EnterpriseApplication3\dist\gfdeploy\EnterpriseApplication3`

Completed initial distribution of *Enterprise Application 3*
Payara Server, deploy, null, false